# How Do I move an Ubuntu GNOME OS from a USB to an HDD?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, usb, hard-drive, transfer

I Have Ubuntu GNOME installed on a 32GB SanDisk USB. I am looking at bringing my OS over to an HDD. Not duplicate of [*How to move 12.04 from USB to HDD?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179293/how-to-move-12-04-from-usb-to-hdd)

This is my file system:

[image: file system]

How do I bring across my OS while keeping it functional?

Can I get the process by which this is done?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu or another distro already installed in your HDD? what do you have in `/dev/sda4` and `/dev/sda5`?

Comment: No other OS on HDD. `/dev/sda4` contains `/var` partition and `/dev/sda5` is `root`.